# Are these miscellaneous problems/oddities during liveUSB normal? (lubuntu 18.10 i386)

Tags: boot, mount, lubuntu, live-usb, 18.10

First I noticed that the USB I'd booted from was listed twice:

[image: listed twice in taskbar]

To investigate, I opened the folder viewer and clicked to see mounted drives, and encountered a second error:

[image: mounting error from clicking navigation bar]

Then, checking out the new qlipper software it seems not to be displaying properly, and clicking on this displayed item does nothing:

[image]

The md5sum matched the stated hash, and I checked disk for errors before starting lubuntu and no errors were found. So is this all normal for various reasons, or should I not try to install from this liveUSB?

Comment: No, those are not usual. Go ahead and install. The worst case would be re-installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First I noticed that the USB I'd booted from was listed twice:

This is normal for the ISO, and can safely be ignored.

> Then, checking out the new qlipper software it seems not to be displaying properly, and clicking on this displayed item does nothing:

That's normal too; Qlipper is super minimal.

Proceed as normal :)